# Calling stored procedures in Laravel 5.5 using SQL Server with output

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I have the following stored procedure:

```
declare @CodigoRet int

exec Generator 'LancaContaContabil', @Codigo = @CodigoRet output

Select @CodigoRet
```

- OBS: the LancaContaContabil is my table and the Codigo is the PK for that table

And I'm trying to call this procedure in Laravel 5.5 but it gives me the error: "The active result for the query contains no fields":

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('DECLARE @CodigoRet INT; execute Generator 
\'LancaContaContabil\', @Codigo = @CodigoRet OUTPUT;'));
echo $results;
die;
```

Same error using the variant without dbraw:

```
$results = DB::select('DECLARE @CodigoRet INT; EXEC Generator         
\'LancaContaContabil\', @Codigo = @CodigoRet OUTPUT;');
echo $results;
die;
```

Also tried with statement, but the return is always 1:

```
$results = DB::statement('DECLARE @CodigoRet INT; EXEC Generator 
\'LancaContaContabil\', @Codigo = @CodigoRet OUTPUT;');
echo $results;
die;
```

EDIT: I created the procedure under the name 'testeproc' and now i've tried this, with the same error as above:

```
$results = DB::select('EXECUTE testeproc');
echo $results;
die;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got it sorted out. I will post here the solution that can help other people with the same problem.

```
$dbh = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC ProcLancaContaContabil");
$sth->execute();
$codigo = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

The trick is to use "SET NOCOUNT ON" before calling the procedure.
I found this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Without parameter:

```
$results = DB::select('EXEC your_stored_procedure');
```

Wit parameters

```
$results = DB::select('exec your_stored_procedure("parameter1", "parameter2",..)');
```

or

```
$results = DB::select('exec your_stored_procedure(?,?,..)',array($parameter1,$parameter2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alessandro, but i've already tried this and the error is the same "The active result for the query contains no fields". Now i've just created a simple procedure to test, with just one select and its working fine. But the output one, still failing.

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri Maybe you cn help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnIdExample
    (
             @paramOne int
            ,@paramTwo nvarchar(255)
    )
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON; --IMPORTANT!

    BEGIN

    -- Grab the id that was just created
    DECLARE @ObjectID int;

    INSERT INTO [Table]
    (
             [ColumnNameA]
            ,[ColumnNameB]
    ) VALUES (
             @paramOne
            ,@paramTwo
    )

    SET @ObjectID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Select the id to return it back to laravel
    SELECT@ObjectID AS ObjectID;

END
```

Calling this Stored Procedure in Laravel Model/Controller:

```
$submit = DB::select("EXEC ReturnIdExample ?,?", array( $paramOne ,$paramTwo ) );
```

Accessing the Return Variable in Laravel Model:

```
return $submit[0]->ObjectId;
```